# How can I get command line arguments(sys.argv) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

filename:test.py

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.argv)
```

I typed `python test.py 1 2 3` in the cmd console , it works well.

```
3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
['test.py', '1', '2', '3']
```

However , I type `test.py 1 2 3` in the cmd console, it can only get the first argument.

```
3.5.0b4 (v3.5.0b4:c0d641054635, Jul 26 2015, 06:55:14) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
['E:\\Bin\\iproc\\test.py']
```

How can I get these arguments ?

Comment: Hm, can't seem to reproduce this. Can you confirm that `E:\Bin\iproc\test.py` is the right copy of `test.py`? Is the `cmd` window finding one in your `PATH` to run instead? The version of PYthon appears to be different, too, which hints it might a different copy.

Comment: `python test.py 1 2 3` and `import sys print(sys.argv)` that's ok http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

Comment: I am sure there is only one copy of  `test.py` in my `PATH` as I run `where test.py`,only one `test.py` is the result.

Comment: I test this file in my debian os , it is ok .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, my Windows file association is bad.I Checked the registry , and finally changed the registry . The problem is solved .

`[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python.exe\shell\open\command]
@="\"c:\\bin\\python35\\python.exe\"  \"%L\" %*"`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your Windows file association is bad.  Make sure arguments are passed as `%%*`.  Use the `assoc` and `ftype` commands in `cmd.exe` to check.  For example:

```
ASSOC .py=Python.File
FTYPE Python.File="C:\Python35\python.exe" "%%1" %%*
```

Comment: It does not work.```c:\bin\python35\python.exe: can't open file '%1': [Errno 2] No such file or directory```

Comment: What didn't work?  Did you get that error from the `ftype` command or when you tried to run the python script?  What does `ftype` show?